# Full time and part time jobs in UK standard visa application

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, egyptian-citizens

I have a full-time job with a fixed salary payable via ATM and another a part-time one with unfixed salary (according to the number of hours/week) payable Cash-in-hand. My bank statement shows both of them.

So, I have two questions:

1. Should I write my full-time job's salary in my regular income question and the part-time one in the another source of income question? or add both together in the first question??
2. About the unfixed salary, How could I write it?? because they need a precise number to mention. Should I write the highest number I could get every month?

Comment: Rather than the highest number every month, I would pick a reasonable time frame (like two or three years) and average your monthly income from that source over that period.  If you pick the highest number, it would look like you are trying to present yourself in a more favorable light than is actually warranted (which you in fact would be doing).  This will cause the officer deciding on your application to view you unfavorably.

Comment: @phoog +1 definitely an answer

Comment: @Dorothy but I have no idea about the answer to the first question.  Mahmoud: perhaps you should ask the questions separately. Edit this question to remove #1 and post that as a new question.  You can link each question to the other.

Comment: @phoog but your analysis, supported by OP bank statements, actually responds to #1, IMO.

Comment: @phoog there is a question saying how much I earn every month, should I add both together?? or to write only the full-time job salary and later i mention that i work part time job?

Answer (score 2):

As you will support your application with bank statements, you may want to show your regular income as the fixed salary from your full time position.

Where you are asked for other source(s) of income, provide an average amount per month derived from your part-time position.

From the accompanying bank statements, an ECO can assess funds available to you. You wouldn't want to inflate your income by what you might hope to get but, rather, you're giving a view of your actual earnings over a period of time.